# jasmine test case for shared service on ngOnInit() shows undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine

In ngOnInit() of a component i am getting an user object from shared service . While writing test case it always returns error as Undefined.

**sharedUser.service.ts**

```
getUserData()
{
    // sends data to component A 
    return this.http.post<User>('api/post', { url:'getUserUrl'});
}



 sendUserData(userResponse:User)
    {
       // sends data from component A to component B
       this.userData =userResponse;
    
    }
```

**componentB.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.userDetail = this.sharedUser.userData;
  this.userHasAccess = this.userDetail.accessCode === 112 ? true : false;
}
```

while writing testcase its throwing error has  cannot set property accessCode of undefined. Please guide me how to write test case for this one.

Answer (score 0):

For unit test cases to run connecting different files, you will have to intantiate it or register it before all test cases . We could use **beforeEach** for that . A sample example below :

**sharedUser.service.ts**

```
export class SharedUser{
 this.userData =10;
    
}
```

**componentB.spec.ts**

```
import {SharedUser} from "./sharedUser.service";
import {componentB} from "./componentB.component";
describe('Testing componentB', () => {

  let service: SharedUser;

  beforeEach(() => { (1)
    service = new SharedUser();
    component = new componentB(service);
  });

  it('check whether we are getting data from service', () => {
    console.log(service.userData) // This should print the data if there is value in it 
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

Attaching a good guide on how mocking and spying can be done which will help you in testing services and async calls:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/

Answer (score 0):

Actually the mistake i did is i was assigning the data directly without checking whether it is defined or not

```
this.userDetail = this.sharedUser.userData; ---> when userData is not available it remains undefined
```

so when i modified as below it worked

```
 this.userDetail = this.sharedUser.userData ? this.sharedUser.userData : {}
```